# Create binary pandas dataframe (optimize loop for)

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, optimization

Imagine I have this dataframe :

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"id" : [0,1,4,3],
                "cit" : [[6,7], [], [9,2,1], [0,1]]})
```

This DataFrame :

```
       id   cit
   0    0   [6, 7]
   1    1   []
   2    4   [9, 2, 1]
   3    3   [0, 1]
```

*(in reality, I have a Dataframe with ~13 000 rows)*

The cit columns are links for id (one way), the id #0 have links with id #6 and id #7, the id #1 have no link, the id #4 have links with #9, #2 and #1 and id #3 have links with id #0 and id #1

if there is a link, I want to put 1 if 2 id are linked, else 0

I want to have this output :

```
id  0   1   4   3
0   X   0   0   1
1   0   X   1   1
4   1   1   X   0
3   1   0   0   X
```

I have written a code but with 2 for loops..
I want to optimize the following code :

```
for i in range(len(test.id)):
   tmp = []
   for j in range(len(test.cit)):
     if test.id.iloc[i] in test.cit.iloc[j]:
        tmp.append(str(1))
     else:
        tmp.append(str(0))
   t2.loc[str(test.id.iloc[i])] = tmp
   print(i, '/' , len(test.id))
t2.values[[np.arange(len(test.id))]*2] = "X"
```

And I don't know how to copy the upper triangular to lower triangular for a DataFrame (I can do it with for loop but 4 for loops with 13 000 rows, it will be very slow..)

I checked the iterrows() and itertuples() functions but I have no idea how can I do it, same for isin() or apply/map() functions..

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new `DataFrame`, and then you can use `pd.crosstab`

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.DataFrame(test.cit.values.tolist(), 
                   index = test.id)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .to_frame())

pd.crosstab(df.index, df[0].values.astype(int)).rename_axis(None,1).rename_axis('id', 0)
```

#### Output:

```
    0  1  2  6  7  9
id                  
0   0  0  0  1  1  0
3   1  1  0  0  0  0
4   0  1  1  0  0  1
```

---

If needed, you can reindex afterwards to then get all rows or all columns. But since your expected output didn't match the data you provided, not sure if that's needed.

Comment: Looking good ! Didn't know there was such a function like that, 
for the 6,7 and 9, I forgot to say there's id who are not in id columns (because of pre-processing filter)